# Mapped drivelabel windows 7 issue

Tags: c#, windows, webdav

I am going crazy with an issue with LABEL of mapping a drive to windows with windows 7 OS. Scenario;

We need to map the drive as soon as user logs in to the machine. That seems to be working fine with other os versions except windows 7. Steps for windows 7;

1. EXE (c# made by us) launched in windows 7
2. EXE has mapped drive correctly
3. User logged out
4. Logged in back
5. Again exe is trying to map drive (Its registered as a startup exe)
6. The mapped drive label becomes "Network Drive" (Not sure how)

We are setting the proper values in registry as well as shown in below figure;

[image]

Problem is here;

[image]

Issue is only occurring when we do logout and login. If we manually launch exe, it works fine...

I have also tried to DELETE all these registry before mapping driving assuming it might be cache or something but nothing helped..

We are using zMapDrive to map a drive;

```
//create struct data
structNetResource stNetRes = new structNetResource();
stNetRes.iScope = 2;
stNetRes.iType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
stNetRes.iDisplayType = 3;
stNetRes.iUsage = 1;
stNetRes.sRemoteName = ls_ShareName;
stNetRes.sLocalName = ls_Drive;       
//prepare params
int iFlags = 0;
if (lf_SaveCredentials) { iFlags += CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED; }
if (lf_Persistent) { iFlags += CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE; }
if (ls_PromptForCredentials) { iFlags += CONNECT_INTERACTIVE + CONNECT_PROMPT; }
if (psUsername == "") { psUsername = null; }
if (psPassword == "") { psPassword = null; }
//if force, unmap ready for new connection
if (lf_Force) { try { zUnMapDrive(true); } catch { } }
//call and return
int i = WNetAddConnection2A(ref stNetRes, psPassword, psUsername, iFlags);
if (i > 0) { throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(i); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simple powershell script, renaming network drive will work for you? You can then use [Task Scheduler](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler) to run it every time a user logs in.

```
$Rename = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$Net = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network

# map the drive if the path doesn't exist
If (!(Test-Path Z:))
{
    $Net.MapNetworkDrive("Z:", '\\SERVER_ADDRESS\Directory', $false, "user", "password")
}

# change the drive name
$Rename.NameSpace("Z:\").Self.Name = "MyNetDriveLabel"
```

From my experience, support for network mapped drives is somewhat buggy in Windows 7, so I use similar workaround on a few of our Win7 machines.

Comment: Hey Michal, Just tried that. I still get the error: http://screencast.com/t/ogwecHajd

Comment: If you see in screenshot, have tried couple of times and even tried getting its value which is coming latest but the UI somehow not picking up...

Comment: Maybe try disconnecting it and then run the script again to allow powershell to map the drive? If that doesn't work then I'm out of ideas, because it works for me perfectly and UI gets refreshed almost instantly.

Comment: Hi Michal, I have managed to solve this issue by using powershell in c# and above script with some modifications. Also have given some breathing time to OS to boot up completely before executing my program.